# How to use a webbrowser as a proxy?

Tags: http, https, webbrowser-control, port

Suppose I am logged in and connected to a website in firefox (or any other browser) now I can make download requests in the browser. Suppose I want to use wget or curl using the connection of firefox. Is there a way to use firefox as a systemwide proxy for port 443 and 80? Here is a usage scenario: This would be interesting for a download manager, if the requests are proxied and made by the browser, all the credentials stored in the browser could be used.
So the browser would receive the request on port 443 and replicate it or forward it. Proxy and forwarding are probably not the right words in this context.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any feature of Firefox (or any other mainstream browser) that allows to really use it as some kind of proxy, sorry.

You cannot somehow "use the connection firefox already has", since there is no permanent connection between client and server in an http communication. http is a stateless protocol without some socket permanently kept open. Instead each http request is sent separately, each time a new socket is opened.

However something similar might be "half possible" using a crude workaround:

What you *can* try however is to simply start a new instance of the browser for each request you want to do. In reality this does *not* start a new instance, but reuses an already existing instance and typically opens a new tab in there. That way you can "remote control" your already started browser in a primitive way and do downloads, *if* and only if the url you specify will result in a download. However that all depends on the browser settings, so for example downloads will be stored in files in your local file system where you have to read the payload from again.

This all is not really efficient and convenient which is why it probably does not make much sense. Instead you should create a simple script for such communication. The effort for that is not that high.

Comment: maybe somebody implemented something similar using the webdriver framework selenium or nodejs. I am almost sure that something like this has already benn written.

Comment: @user22207 As written: "I am not aware of"... Though I do not understand how nodejs should come into play.